# TCPDF: Two Independent Columns with page break

Tags: php, tcpdf

I want to create a page with 2 independent columns. If the text does not fit in one colum on one page it should be continued on the next page with the same column setup.

I tried using setColumnsArray and selectColumn the problem with this is, that if the first column is full it continues on the next column instead on the next page.

It there a posibility to achive this?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem now without writing everything in html. 
I used to following aproache:

1. Save the top of the columns with getY and getPage.
2. Write the first column
3. Use setY and setPage to go back to the top of the second column
4. Use setX to move the seconds column on the right side.
5. Using the following hack to get around the problem with different page borders on right and left pages on the second column:

   ```
   if ($curPage<>$pdf->getPage())
   {
     $curPage=$pdf->getPage();
     if (($curPage % 2)==1)
     {
       $xPos+=15;
     }
     else          
     {
       $xPos-=15;
     }
   }
   $pdf->SetX($xPos);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

See Sample10 which is doing exactly what you are asking for:

- PHP Source code: http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_010.phps
- Final PDF: http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_010.pdf

Sample7 might help too but column spreads over multiple pages:

- PHP Source code: http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_007.phps
- Final PDF: http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_007.pdf

Comment: Unfortunately Exmaple 10 ist exactly the wrong. Text starts in the first column on page one and continues on the seconds column on page one. I want it to continue on the first column ob page 2

Example 7 is more what I need, but right now the content of the columns is not one HTML String, but several HTML cells and Image.

Comment: I don't understand the problem, if Example 7 is what you need, just update the $left_column PHP variable to add your own content, including images.

Comment: The problem with Example 7 is, that I would have to do everything in html. The colummn ist a bit complex with different boxes background colors, images and text on the images. I am not sure if I can reproduce this in html.